# "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table" in rails model inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

When I run

```
irb(main):003:0> House.new(name: "A house")
```

I get the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'houses'
    from /home/overflow012/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:429:in `table_structure'
...
```

You can see my code below

**property.rb**

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
    self.abstract_class = true
end
```

**apartment.rb**

```
class Apartment < Property
end
```

**house.rb**

```
class House < Property
end
```

**db/migrate/20160616022800_create_properties.rb**

```
class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :detail
      t.float :price
      t.string :type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And the properties table was created via `rake db:migrate`
[image]
**Note**: I'm using rails 5.0.0.rc1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried without `Property` as an abstract class?

Comment: I don't understand why but It's works! Thank you! In the domain problem, property it is an abstract concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to remove the `self.abstract_class` line from your `Property` model.

Adding `abstract_class` to the model will force child classes to bypass the implied STI table naming of the parent class `Property`. Essentially, we're saying `Property` can no longer be instantiated, and is not backed by a database table.

Therefore, child classes of `Property` are not going to look to the parent class for the table name, they will look for a table based on their own class name.

Alternatively, you could set `self.table_name = 'properties'` in your `Property` model and that should work. However, this defeats the purpose of defining an `abstract_class`.